# Automatically fix outstanding mathjax issue involving backticks

Tags: feature-request, support

After the transition to the stack exchange network, I have occasionally noticed posts being edited to replace occurrences of the following code (note the backticks):

```
`\[ some math here \]`
```

with

```
$$ some math here $$
```

Most recently, such an edit was made to the question [Homotopy type of tensors of Moore spectra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85313/homotopy-type-of-tensors-of-moore-spectra). These edits are infrequent, but still recurrent.

> Can someone with access to the database find all occurrences of such code (and perhaps some variations of it) and automatically make the replacement?

Comment: I took the liberty of changing this from a [meta-tag:discussion] to a [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: @Scott: Thanks.

Comment: @ScottMorrison: I have a couple of questions. Would this question warrant the tag 'bug', even if tangentially? Also, would tagging the question 'bug' get a quicker developer reaction on this matter?

Comment: Good question. I can email the stackexchange folks to remind them of this. More generally, I think we need better triaging of [meta-tag:feature-request]s and [meta-tag:bug]s, so everyone knows what's happening.

Comment: Thanks, @Scott. Please let me know if you learn something useful. The feedback on feature-requests is very scarce. Any suggestions on how we should perform this triaging?