# Do we have an unofficial quota on how many old questions one should bump for minor edits in a single day?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, editing, bumping

I noticed tonight that a well-intentioned user has been doing a lot of minor edits of formatting of old questions with the effect of filling most of the active question list with old questions bumped by minor edits.  Did we ever reach some sort of consensus as too how many minor edits a user should restrict themselves to in a single day?  I know on the old meta, now known as tea, such issues were discussed.

Comment: In my opinion one should not do minor edits to more than 3-5 old posts in a 5 hour time period. Doing say 8 minor edits in a short burst can fill almost the entire active question list with old questions which means that new questions may be missed.

Comment: I agree that bumping lots of posts to the front page is undesirable. Nevertheless, I would like to say that at least several of the edits in question corrected mathjax rendering problems. In fact, it was this recent series of edits which led me to start the thread http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/598/list-of-recurrent-technical-problems-involving-mathjax.

Comment: Why does editing bump questions to the front page? Is there an official explanation? Why does an edit cause the post to be bumped, but a comment doesn't? Just to be clear, I'm not saying a post should or shouldn't be bumped when edited, I'd just like to see the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Of course, everything depends on the way you are viewing questions (whether you choose newest tab, active tab, ...) A list of things that cause bump is given at meta.SO: [What can cause my question to be bumped?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped) See also [tag-wiki for (bump)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bump/info).

Comment: It's there to stop malicious edits from going unnoticed. I'm not sure why it's still necessary now that low rep edits go through an approval process.

Comment: @NoahSnyder: I agree with the first sentence. But do not understand the second one. Before low-reo users could not edit others' posts *at all* and editing their own does not go through review. (So there seems no 'security-improvement' relative to before.)

Comment: I would like to underline one point @MartinSleziak mentions in passing, namely, that 'active' is not the *only* tab (but precisely the one that shows "every" activity). When I do not have much time for visiting MO frequently, I browse **newest** where I get all (new) questions ordered in reverse chronological order (nothing whatsoever causes any bumps in that tab). Newest is a bit limiting, but 'hot' could be a reasonable compromise (not everything that bumps in 'active' bumps in 'hot', eg pure tag-edits do not show up in 'hot').

Comment: @NoahSnyder: The approval process would be enough if all reviewers actually looked at what they approve. But experience shows that some of them don't, as witnessed in [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155561) on meta.SO. People manage to approve suggested edits such as [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/71173) on other sites.

Comment: @quid, but active is very convenient for seeing new answers. If you answer a question and it immediately gets bumped off the active page then few people will see your answer.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: yes, I partly agree. Still, sometimes one can get away with the impression that some (not you specifically) do not really realize there are other tabs too, and since you explcitly mentioned the risk of missing a *question* I mentioned it.  However, I am also not sure the effect is as large as you describe. Namely, I think it is an oversimplifcation to assume that there is an absolute or even very strong correlation with things getting looked at an their precise position in the active queue. Sure I an I assume many/most others start looking at the top of it, but then [cont]

Comment: *if* at the top there is nothing interesting (to me) or new (but just some edits) then I look further down not paying much attention or investing much time in the things at the top-position and thus in the time-span I intend to stay on the site arrive at going further down than if everything at the top was interesting/new. (Sure it might happen some old post only bumped due to an edit starts to interest  me as perhaps I had never seen it before, and so I read it instead of something newer, but then if I found it interesting it is not so clear what is lost). In addition [cont]

Comment: I am a bit unsure what you mean by 8 questions filling almost the entire question active question list. The frontpage (when logged in) holds a lot more than 8 questions (at least for me, though this might depend), and if one actually goes to /questions than it is 'infinite.' In view of what I said regarding the not spending much time, I sometimes even think whether doing edits in larger bursts would not be better, since then if somebody sees say 15 questions all modified by the same users within half an hour, they might infer this is very likely only minor edits and skip that block.

Comment: A bit off-topic here but just as a vague idea, perhaps to get realized a feature-request for an *additional* tab (say, containing only new questions and answers), or a replacement of another one (say 'hot') by this, would have more chance of success than the 'minor edits should not bump' request.

Comment: @Martin that math.SE example is really extreme, almost makes me believe they let it go through on purpose.

Comment: @quid: I would upvote a feature request for a new tab like that. Unfortunately, such a feature is unlikely to ever see the light of day, judging by how most feature requests are ignored...

Comment: How about a "minor edit" flag?

Comment: @RicardoAndrade: I would love to see a feature request that asks for feature requests to be addressed!

Comment: I think filling the active questions with lots of edits is particularly bothersome for those who mostly us MO on mobile devices because only a handful of questions are visible without scrolling in mobile mode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The OP wrote: *I know on the old meta, now known as tea, such issues were discussed.* I am collecting here some relevant threads which I was able to locate. I am making this CW - feel free to add more links, if you consider them relevant.

- [Editing old answers by other users](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/1575/editing-old-answers-by-other-users/); François G. Dorais said there: "It's fine and encouraged to improve old questions and answers. However, keep in mind that it's mildly annoying to have many old questions bumped up to the front page at once, *3 edits per day is acceptable*."
- [Must we raise the dead for umlaut's sake](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/1374/must-we-raise-the-dead-for-umlauts-sake/); Gerry Myerson's advice: "Re-tag *two or three questions a day* until they're all done."

Comment: Just to confirm, the first is the last official (ie, moderator) mention of this I remember (and I am pretty sure it is actually the last) so it might qualify as current "official guideline."

Comment: I agree with the "two or three a day" limit.  For ALL edits of stale questions, major or minor.

Comment: It's odd to be reminded of the verse / I used to try; but now it's even worse

Comment: At the moment, links to tea do not work. Here are snapshots of the two links in the Internet Archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20151031150220/http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1575/editing-old-answers-by-other-users/ and http://web.archive.org/web/20151031173230/http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1374/must-we-raise-the-dead-for-umlauts-sake/

Answer (score 13):

I believe that I am the user that you are referring to. I apologise to anyone I have inconvenienced.

The majority of the edits that I have done over this short period of time were fixing very similar errors which caused the output to split over several lines. I think I got carried away because I wanted to fix all of them (there aren't that many to fix). However, I did not think about the effect I was having on the front page. I will take a break from these edits for the rest of the day, but (if it's OK with everyone) I will continue to do one or two a day so that all instances of this error are rectified within a week or so.

Comment: Dear @Michael: I would greatly appreciate it if you could describe those mathjax problems in the thread http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/598/list-of-recurrent-technical-problems-involving-mathjax.

Comment: Michael, I would like to thank you for your efforts to edit and improve questions and answers here on MO; it is appreciated by many of us, and I hope you continue to do this.

Comment: These are needed edits. It would be nice if they could be done automatically. Since that does not seem to be the case, this seems the best solution we currently have.

Comment: I have no problems with the edits. I just recommend in smaller bursts, maybe 3 at a time.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade: Will do.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: No worries. I will continue to edit posts but I will try to space them out.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I agree, I will be more mindful in future.

Answer (score 10):

Today, I have spotted Pietro Majer bumping close to 20 (and counting...) of his answers to the front page with minor edits. (Sorry to be so blunt in naming a respected user, but I guess I'm a little annoyed.)

Comment: Perhaps a comment on one of his answers might get quicker results?  Hey, @Pietro!  Slow down please!

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger I did that. No response.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Just seen this (this follows on from some minor but justified edits yesterday). I'm not keen on the extent of today's bumping either

Comment: After analysing a few of Pietro's edits, it appears he is mostly replacing double backslashes `\\ ` in mathjax: this seems to now be non-functioning, yet harmless, code. In an attempt to prevent this from happening again in the future, I bumped my request to automatically fix these minor mathjax issues to the top, and turned it into a feature request.

Comment: In the meantime, I also left a comment in one of Pietro's recently edited answers, as Todd Trimble and Yemon Choi did before me. As it stands now, the front page consists mostly (~35/50) of posts with answers which have been edited by Pietro less than two hours ago.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade: Thank you! That's a good request.

Comment: @Todd Trimble: Let us hope that the developers pay attention to the request... By the way, for the record, there has been no new edit by Pietro Majer in the last 25 minutes.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade Heh. It was good while it lasted. (Actually, I'm rather surprised, as I even went so far to flag one of the edited answers to get moderator attention, and figured the hiatus in activity was due to a discreet request from a moderator).

Comment: Hi everybody, I noticed your messages and I understand now the terrible effect of my recent minor edits (I always keep the "newest" list and noticed nothing). Anyway, my excuses for the trouble! 
This afternoon I had some free time and thought to fix the format of old posts of mine once and for all (after the recent upgrade of the system, the // does not produces a space anymore, but breaks the lines, which is somehow annoying). 
Cheers, P.

Comment: @PietroMajer: many thanks for your response! I understand your own annoyance. Hopefully Ricardo's request can be implemented.

Comment: I said above that `\\ ` (double backslash followed by a space) is harmless. However, that statement was not correct. It actually creates a new line when mathjax is rendered using CSS or using SVG. Interestingly, when using mathml to render mathjax in at least two browsers, it appears that `\\ ` is simply ignored and does not create a new line.

Answer (score 9):

It's happening again, more than 15 minor edits by one user. Clearly it is just not well known how much this affects the "Active" view. The view by newest Questions is unaffected. I have no suggestion, aside from revisiting "[Silent” Edits for MO](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/784/6094)?"

Comment: Maybe ońe should contact the editor. These edits are really minor and the questions old.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: The editor is not the key problem, it's the reviewers who approved the edits who did them all at once.

Comment: @François G. Dorais: That’s true, but OTOH notifying one editor of the problem is feasible, whereas notifying all potential reviewers is not.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais, it is both but I agree with Emil. I normally reject all minor edits, especially on old questions but I suspect I am in the minority and in any event I almost never review because in the mobile version of the site the Review section is not so accessible.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: I can (and will) notify the reviewers in question. I don't think it's their fault though since the reviewing system encourages dealing with these in batches.

Comment: I thought the system randomly assigns reviews to any currently active users with sufficient reputation (2K?). What I meant is that you can’t notify all of them *before* they have a chance of approving the edit, short of some kind of a site notice.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Yes, I can't catch it beforehand but I did write to the users who approved the recent batch to make them aware of the issue and to ask their input on ways to deal with it.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais what course of action would you propose for a reviewer in such a situation. I can approve/reject/skip. If I reject the edit, it is "gone" I think (except somebody else approves it of course) which seems highly inefficient. Now, if I skip, somboy else will get it possibly not being aware of the earlier edits or in any case in the same situation. Both to reject an edit because of timing (and thus 'destroying' the work that went into it) as well as some mass-skiping to spread it out seems unreasonable or infeasible.

Comment: This was written before your last comment @FrançoisG.Dorais but I think it is sort of impossible to deal with this in a more reasonable way *once the edits are proposed*. The only thing I could imagine is that as soon as one notices siomebody proposing too many edits one tells them to stop. This is possible for normal users too as one can comment notify a person havin edited something so one could comment on a just edited post. [To avoid confusion, it was not me who apporved anything here.]

Comment: I have just rejected a POINTLESS bit of TeXifying, and think those of us who find such edits should reject, contrary to @quid's remark

Comment: @quid: Only a handful of users regularly look at suggested edits and most deal with them in batches. Raising awareness won't eliminate the problem but it will have some effect.

Comment: I should emphasise that my distaste for excessive editing here arises from my past experience doing some freelance copy-editing, which has led me to (a) believe in house style (b) wish sleeping dogs were left to rest unless waking them serves a purpose beyond making the editor feel pleased/busy/smug

Comment: I'm a reviewer who did a bunch of these at once.  I wasn't thinking about the problem this was causing in terms of bumping old questions.  There is no way to have an option to have an edit that doesn't bump?  I'm not really convinced this is a serious problem though.

Comment: @YemonChoi if you think the edit is "POINTLESS" it is of course your right or perhaps even duty to reject it. What I said or at least meant to say is that I do not think it is a good idea to reject an edit you/I/one would otherwise approve *only* because of timing.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais not at all sure about this. I am third by number of reviews so can be considered very active there. Hardly ever do I come across there being more than 2 pending suggestions. More generally, most of the time all suggestions are dealt with very or quite close in time they are suggested. Some are more one the site and/or quicker to react than others, but in principle I think not few look at these suggstions, also as the pending suggestions are made so very visible (as opposed to other review types).

Comment: @quid: Indeed, you almost never review more than 2 edits in a row. Other users do long batches of 5 or more in a row. Those are the reviewers that need to be aware of this issue.

Comment: @KarlSchwede. I think it is a real problem. At the moment the oldest post on the front page is 6 hours old and on a regular day the oldest would be maybe twice that. If you're asking a technical question that only one or two users on the site know how to answer, then the chance that one of these people sees your question drops drastically if posts get bumped off the front page this quickly.

Comment: @DanPetersen I understand, I just tend to look only at tags I am interested in, via the "newest" tab.  In which case this sort of thing never shows up.  I realize that other people display things differently, but I'm not quite sure what the correct thing to do is (see quid's comments).

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais I do not want to insist too much on this, but I just roughly checked the history, ignoring the last hours, the first time I found a string of 5 was on August 23rd! There was none of size 4 until that time, and a handful of 3-strings. It simply hardly ever happens that anybody would even have the chance to make such a long string as typically there simply is no sizeable batch.

Answer (score 6):

Some time ago, still unaware of the mechanism of the *active tab*, I had the idea of correcting the wrong spelling of the name "Hölder", too often written "Holder" by laziness or ignorance, in every occurrence in MO posts. As a result, we had a huge wave of Hölder-related questions over all MO users, a fact I was sincerely sorry about (my excuses again). However, I completely forgot the incident and unfortunately I happened to do the same some days ago, this  time in order to eliminate the annoying double backslash. I am now sure that I will never do that again. Nevertheless I think the MO archive of questions and answers is a very rich and useful source, so that we should find a way to allow and even promote improvements of older posts, especially about making corrections and adding new links and references. Certainly, a good compromise is to introduce a bound on the number of minor edits. Yet some edits, like the above mentioned, would be done better if all at a time, once and for all. So my modest proposal is the following:
**Allow free edits on some special days.** How often, it has to be decided.  So everybody will be prepared to see, say, on the first Sunday of every month, the  active tab turned into a total mess, wildly shaken all day long.

Comment: Dear @Pietro Majer: Your proposal may warrant creating a new thread for its discussion.