# Garbled MathJax in a link to a question with MathJax in the title

Tags: bug, mathjax, profile-page

The following occurs on my activity page:

[image]

The question it links to is [Is there an explicit expression for Chebyshev polynomials modulo $x^r-1$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/286626/41291) and it seems that the MathJax in the end somehow got superimposed at the beginning of the link text.

This happens on Windows 10, Chrome 76.0.3809.132 (64-bit)

Don't know if this might be useful for anything but when I right-click on the link that superimposed thing disappears.

Maybe I should add this issue to the [List of recurrent technical problems involving MathJax](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/598/41291) but it seems not to satisfy conditions given there.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not able to see this myself when I visit your page.

Comment: @ToddTrimble On the [activity tab](https://mathoverflow.net/users/41291/მამუკა-ჯიბლაძე?tab=topactivity) in the reputation column.

Comment: This seems to be a similar problem to this bug recently reported on [math.meta.se]: [MathJax “jumbled up” in the activity tab of a user](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30644). (As a side note, the tag ([meta-tag:profile-page]) might be suitable for this question - after all, that's where the problem manifests.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, I understood that, but still didn't see it.

Comment: I'm on Firefox 68.0.2, using MacOS Mojave 10.14.2.

Comment: Probably I should have linked to the [summary subtab](https://mathoverflow.net/users/41291/მამუკა-ჯიბლაძე?tab=summary) - but I think that it's chosen by default when displaying activity tab of some user for the first time. Anyway, Todd Trimble's comment suggests that there is most likely a difference between various browsers, the same was suggested in comments on the [meta question from the nearby site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30644) that I linked above. (I have added a bit more details in [MO chatroom}(https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51606292#51606292).)

Comment: The bug does not manifest for me. However, looking at the examples, it is likely connected to the fact that the part of the text that includes the MathJax expression is actually hidden (replaced with ...). Presumably the code responsible for calling MathJax erroneously makes it render despite it being hidden.